# In Troposphere, how do I add CustomOriginConfig object

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, troposphere

Using troposhphere, I am trying to add CustomOriginConfig to my CloudFront distribution.

```
.....
Origins = [Origin(
                Id = Join("", ["cloudfront-", Ref("ParamOriginName")]),
                DomainName = Ref("ParamOriginName"),
                CustomOriginConfig(
                    OriginProtocolPolicy = "https-only",
                    OriginSSLProtocols = ["TLSv1.1"]
                )
            )],
.....
```

This fails to build, giving the following error:

```
CustomOriginConfig(
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I have looked at [this](https://any-api.com/amazonaws_com/cloudfront/docs/_2018_11_05_distribution/CreateDistribution) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946936/how-to-set-the-origin-path-on-an-custom-origin-using-cloudformation) and I think that my syntax is correct.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable, whose value is the CustomOriginConfig object

```
Origins = [Origin(
              Id = Join("", ["cloudfront-", Ref("ParamOriginName")]),
              DomainName = Ref("ParamOriginName"),
              CustomOriginConfig = CustomOriginConfig(
                  OriginProtocolPolicy = "https-only",
                  OriginSSLProtocols = ["TLSv1.1"]
              )
          )],
```